# Still return records if unsatisfied cross join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

I have a table (Name: Sales) about when and what customers purchase:

```
Date      C_Name      Thing 
02/21       A         Fruit
02/26       A         Doll
02/27       A         Drink
02/28       B         Book
06/03       B         Fruit
06/13       B         Shoes
06/10       C         Shoes
07/07       A         Tablet
07/11       A         Chair
07/20       A         Sofa
07/21       A         Coat
```

And I need to return the first four items purchased by every customer each month, if the items were purchased in a month were less than four, the return should still see the records. Desired Output:

```
Date(Month) C_Name Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4
2            A     Fruit   Doll   Drink  
2            B     Book
6            B     Fruit   Shoes 
             .  
             . 
             .
7            A     Tablet  Chair  Sofa Coat
```

My current code is as follow, which only can show if the customer purchased equal or more than four objects:

```
SELECT MONTH(s1.Date) AS Date(Month), s1.C_Name, s1.Thing, s2.Thing, s3.Thing, s4.Thing
FROM Sales as s1, Sales as s2, Sales as s3, Sales as s4
ON s1.C_Name = s2.C_Name = s3.C_Name = s4.C_Name
      AND s1.Date<s2.Date 
      AND s2.Date<s3.Date
      AND s3.Date<s4.Date
      AND MONTH(s1.Date) = MONTH(s2.Date)= MONTH(s3.Date)= MONTH(s4.Date);
```

Is there any solution for me to change my code?

Comment: You should not be using [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), instead use correct, modern join syntax. And I don't think your current query would work, because you don't use the `ON` clause for old style joins, you use the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: And if you are wanting row where records are missing you need a different join type. If you post your sample data as DDL+DML you'd make it much easier for someone to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) + [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
with 
t1 as
(
    select   *, format(Date,'yyyy-MM') as month
    from     Sales
),
t2 as
(
    select  'Thing' 
          + cast(row_number() over 
                  (
                      partition by C_Name, month
                      order by Date
                  ) as varchar(10)
            ) as thing_id
           ,month
           ,C_Name
           ,Thing
    
    from    t1
)
select *
from   t2 pivot (min(Thing) for thing_id in ([Thing1],[Thing2],[Thing3],[Thing4])) as p
```

| month | C_Name | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Thing4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02 | A | Fruit | Doll | Drink |  |
| 2021-07 | A | Tablet | Chair | Sofa | Coat |
| 2021-02 | B | Book |  |  |  |
| 2021-06 | B | Fruit | Shoes |  |  |
| 2021-06 | C | Shoes |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b3afca0301057b5318fba068f6c2b30)