# Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')' SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question built from this question ([Still return records if unsatisfied cross join condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532974/still-return-records-if-unsatisfied-cross-join-condition/71533518#71533518)).
The database for this question is extended and provided below.

My desired output is to show the first four things bought in a month, and if bought on the same day, output the one with a larger amount.

I have added `d_thing_id` to see which thing, bought on the same day, has a larger amount.

However, I keep getting an error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Data:

```
create table Sales
(
    Date datetime, 
    C_Name char(1), 
    Thing varchar(100), 
    Amount int
)

insert into Sales (Date, C_Name, Thing, Amount) 
values   ('2021-02-21','A','Fruit', 20)
        ,('2021-02-22','A','Bottle', 15)
        ,('2021-02-22','A','Straw', 7)
        ,('2021-02-26','A','Doll' , 31)
        ,('2021-02-27','A','Drink', 29)
        ,('2021-02-27','A','Bread', 30)
        ,('2021-02-28','B','Book' , 67)
        ,('2021-06-03','B','Fruit' , 100)
        ,('2021-06-13','B','Shoes' , 10)
        ,('2021-06-10','C','Shoes', 90)
        ,('2021-07-07','A','Tablet', 4)
        ,('2021-07-11','A','Chair' , 77)
        ,('2021-07-11','A','Cushion', 43)
        ,('2021-07-20','A','Sofa' , 37)
        ,('2021-07-21','A','Coat' , 66)
```

Code

```
with d1(Date, C_Name, Thing, Amount, Month) as
(
    select *, month(Date) as Month
    from Sales
),
d2 (thing_id, Month, C_Name, Thing) as
(
    select 
        'Thing' + cast(row_number() over (partition by C_Name, Month
                                          order by Date) as varchar(10)) as thing_id
           ,Month
           ,C_Name
           ,Thing
    from d1
    where 
        (select row_number() over (partition by C_Name, Month, Date
                                   order by Date, Amount desc) as d_thing_id
         from d1
         where d_thing_id = 1)
)
select *
from d2 
pivot 
    (min(Thing) 
         for thing_id in ([Thing1], [Thing2], [Thing3])
    ) as p;
```

**EDIT**

My expected output

```
month C_Name Thing1 Thing2 Thing3 Thing4
2       A    Fruit  Bottle  Doll  Bread
2       B    Fruit
6       B    Fruit  Shoes
6       C    Shoes
7       A    Tablet Chair  Sofa  Coat
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Kendle Hi! I've added my expected output!

Comment: WHERE clause in the second CTE is not correct. It is not compared with any thing.

Answer (score 0):

this where clause has no `operator`

```
  where   (select row_number() over 
                  (
                      partition by C_Name, Month, Date
                      order by Date, Amount DESC
                  ) as d_thing_id
             from d1
             where d_thing_id = 1
            )
```

It should be more like this for example

```
  where   (select row_number() over 
                  (
                      partition by C_Name, Month, Date
                      order by Date, Amount DESC
                  ) as d_thing_id
             from d1
             where d_thing_id = 1
            ) = something
```